# Query statement with session variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Is it right to use session variables in a SQL query?

I have a query:

```
$sql="SELECT teacher.f_name,attendance.student_id,attendance.SNO ,attendance.s_section,attendance.DateTime FROM teach,subject,teacher,attendance  WHERE teach.teacher_id= $_SESSION['username'] AND $_SESSION['username'] = teacher.teacher_id AND teach.SNO = subject.SNO";
```

I used session here from the previous page which the user sign in then save the username variable to a session and redirect tho this page where the query here

The output tells me "syntax error" in `WHERE` statement line.

Comment: It is **never** right to build a query with variable interpolation or string concatenation, regardless of the source of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Change `AND $_SESSION['username'] = teacher.teacher_id` to `AND teacher.teacher_id = $_SESSION['username']`
Then change all `$_SESSION['username']` to `{$_SESSION['username']}`